# How can I load a web font such as font awesome on page load?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, webfonts

This question applies to situations where the web font isn't required on the main page and is initially inside a `div` set to `display:none;`

I have a web page that loads a hidden form via Javascript on click and this form uses a web font. My issue is that there is a one second delay when the user clicks to reveal the form, as it is at that moment Chrome downloads the `woff2` file.

This isn't very nice for the user experience.

I need to preload the webfont as I have no usage for the font on the main page, so there is nothing to cause Chrome to fetch the `woff2` file before the users clicks to reveal the hidden form.

I noticed that this doesn't matter if you're hosting the Font Awesome on your server or using the CDN.

I looked around on the internet to see what could be done, I tried all of the below and none of it helped, nothing caused the `woff2` file to load on page load, it only ever loaded when the webpage actively needed the font.

**Attempt 1: Preload**

```
<link rel="preload" href="form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2">
```

or

```
<link rel="preload" href="form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font">
```

**Attempt 2: Prefetch**

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2">
```

**Attempt 3: CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font-Awesome';
    src: url('form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format("woff2");;
}
```

As I was looking around I started to see possible solutions with Javascript based loading, something I really didn't want to go near, so what are my options here?

Comment: which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up with this simple solution, it hasn't been tested on anything other than Chrome but it's pretty basic for my use case, I can't imagine it not working on any modern browser.

I decided to force load the `woff2` file by loading a font onto my main page, but ensure that the users can't see it.

As I already discovered, Chrome does not fetch resources that are required by any `div` that is set to `display:none;`

So here is my solution instead.

**CSS**

```
.div-fake-hidden {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- This fake div hidden preloads our web font! -->
<div class="div-fake-hidden"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-3x"></i></div>
```

Now the browser loads the `woff2` resource on page load, so that when my users click a button to reveal the hidden form, the web font loads immediately.

Comment: Tested with latest Firefox and Edge. Works also on both of them.

Comment: Worked on Firefox 71.0 (64-bit) as well, thank you Hackerman! @Joseph

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a hidden div to make your font work. As long as you're using a supported browser (picture from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)) the css `@font-face` rule should work fine.

[image]

You can also add more font formats as follows:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Font-Awesome';
src: url('form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format("woff2"),
url('form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
url('form/font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: I can see there that it says Chrome should have worked, but it wouldn't preload the `woff2` file during my tests.

Comment: Are you actually using the font in the webpage outside the hidden div?

Comment: Yes, but only on a hidden form that is shown when the user presses a submit button, then jQuery removes my `div-hidden` class from the second form and it's on this form that I am using Font Awesome.

That's my issue, the Font Awesome isn't needed until I unhide the form (I am using the Font Awesome for check boxes). It's all on the same page though, but Chrome will not load the `woff2` file until my jQuery unhides the form. This results in a very ugly delay.


However, no page reload occurs, it is all on the same page.

Comment: Can you include Font-awesome somewhere else on the page that isn't initially hidden? Headers? Paragraphs? Titles?

Comment: Or maybe you could have the hidden from start out as unhidden and hide it after .5 seconds or something. Then the font would begin loading before the user opens the form...

Comment: Yeah, I added it into my CSS as above (attempt 3) which is entirely loaded on page load. But Chrome refused to fetch the `woff2` file until the form was unhidden. I might try @font-face in Firefox to see if that works there.

Comment: I can't have my form unhidden, it will be too noticeable even for a split second. At the moment my solution does work and results in no delays as the font isn't required until the hidden form is unhidden. Of course it's none standard but probably universal,

Answer (score -1):

You could try using Web Font Loader: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

> Web Font Loader gives you added control when using linked fonts via @font-face. It provides a common interface to loading fonts regardless of the source, then adds a standard set of events you may use to control the loading experience. The Web Font Loader is able to load fonts from Google Fonts, Typekit, Fonts.com, and Fontdeck, as well as self-hosted web fonts. It is co-developed by Google and Typekit.